# Adding Arrow Key Functionality to a REPL written in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, interpreter

I am currently going through a tutorial on writing a Scheme interpreter with Haskell. I would really like to add the ability to use the arrow keys to recall previously entered lines and correct typos without deleting every preceding character.

I figure I can save previously input expressions in a list and traverse the list when the arrow keys are hit, but I am not sure how to automatically detect the key. All of my IO experience has involved the user actually pressing "Enter", so I am not sure how I would go about detecting the arrow key.

Any resources / advice would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the haskeline package.

Comment: I'll also put in a plug for rlwrap. Use it to run your program, and it will provide the line editing & history capabilities for you.